# Redirect page with passing value

Tags: php, html

I have a real problem and it's syntax problem. Normally when I need redirect any page I just use header function. Sometimes I use a variable when I need like below:

```
if(condition) header("Location: home.php?wrong=1");
```

Sometimes it could be:

```
if(condition) header("Location: home.php?wrong=1&&success=2");
```

There is no problem with direct use of variable(wrong or success). And when I need redirect a value from html form via post method, I use this code and it works:

```
if (condition) header("Location: home.php?id=".$_POST['topic_id']);
```

But I need more, I need pass another value too. So I use:

```
if (condition) header("Location: home.php?id=".$_POST['topic_id']&&wrong=1);
```

And this time I become a dumb. Can anyone help me out by providing proper syntax? I just need pass the WRONG=1 part too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need:

```
if (condition) header("Location: home.php?id=" . $_POST['topic_id'] . "&wrong=1");
```

or

```
if (condition) header("Location: home.php?id={$_POST['topic_id']}&wrong=1");
```

Comment: Is the useless double `&` intentionally retained in your answer? Regardless, +1 for fixing the PHP syntax error.

Comment: @Vulcan I noticed it and took it out before you clicked `Add Comment`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response. I am grateful to you. It works.

Comment: No problem, If it works for you make sure to select an answer by clicking the check mark

Comment: I was trying but it said I need wait for 10 minutes to do that. Don't worry, I will.

Answer (score 1):

some times it could be

```
if (condition) {
  $_SESSION['error']['topicId'] = $_POST['topic_id'];
  $_SESSION['error']['otherData'] = array('sadfasdfasdfasd' => 'adsfasdf');
  header("Location: home.php?wrong=1");
  exit;
}
```

and then:

```
//home.php
if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
  $topicId = $_SESSION['error']['topicId'];
  //... do someth ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is any problem with PHP header function, you may keep in mind that you are able to printout the refresh meta tag in your script HTML output.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://yoursite.com/thepath/you/want/file.php?parames=anything">
```

This is a resource about meta refresh tag:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm